# How do I disassemble this old bed frame?

Tags: bedroom, frame, bed

Does anyone have any ideas on how to disassemble this bed frame?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hold the wood frame down.

Hit the steel frame up.  If like pain use your hand/fist.  I prefer a hammer or heavy object/tool.

Pull the wood away from the steel hooks.

The steel hooks lay on top of steel pins in the wood frame.

Newer frames should go on/come off by hand with a little force, older frames usually need more force to loosen them apart.  Where a hammer comes in handy.

Comment: I kind of tried that, even with a hammer, but it's really stuck. Maybe I need more muscle power to get this thing loose?

Comment: @Amanda   More force will help.  Might need to turn it upside down, with the wood on soft patches(carpet pieces) to give the steel frame a good wack.  Or use 2x4s to raise the frame above the floor by an inch, raise the corner up and slam it down.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'll let you know how it goes when I have an extra set of hands. Thank you! @crip659

Comment: Block the steel frame up (pile of wood, pile of books, whatever) until the foot of the frame is an inch or so off the floor. Pad the wood frame so as not to damage it, or use a rubber mallet, or both, and hit it downwards. *Much* easier than turning the frame over, or picking up the frame and slamming it down.

Comment: put something solid under the metal and drop the bed frame so the metal hits it.  the more "anvil like"  the better.

Comment: It'll also help to remove the mattress if you're trying the "hammer the frame up" method...